# ReactJS: state not updated after setState and callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this are my initial state:

```
this.state = {
  requiredError: false,
  addressSelectError: false,
  recipientError: false,
  open: false,
};
```

and this is where my problem is:

```
processCheckout () {
    this.setState({
      requiredError: true, 
      addressSelectError: true,
      recipientError: true,
    }, () => {
      console.log('required error', requiredError);
      console.log('address error', addressSelectError);
      console.log('recipient error', recipientError);
    })
}
```

I have set them all to `true` but the console still logs false:

[image]

I have used the callback but it still does not change. any help?

I am calling the `processCheckout()` function on `onClick()` of a button.

EDIT: I have tried console logging in render, and all of them are `true`

Comment: Can you show the full code of where you are updating the state

Comment: Where have you defined requiredError, addressSelectError and recipientError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the entire code I assume you've declared the variables 
`requiredError, addressSelectError and recipientError` somewhere in your class:

In the callback, try to access this.state directly

```
processCheckout() {

    this.setState(
      {
        requiredError: true,
        addressSelectError: true,
        recipientError: true
      },
      () => {
        console.log("required error", this.state.requiredError);
        console.log("address error", this.state.addressSelectError);
        console.log("recipient error", this.state.recipientError);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have declared them like this `const { requiredError, addressSelectError, recipientError } = this.state;` before the `setState` and I thought that's the same. but when I tried your answer it works, why is that? and also thanks!

Comment: When you declare ```const { requiredError, addressSelectError, recipientError } = this.state;``` in your processCheckout method they reference the state at the current state. In this case ```requiredError, addressSelectError, recipientError``` are all false since they are defined false in your constructor method.

Answer (score 2):

Change your function to an arrow syntax so it has access to the global state.

```
processCheckout= () => {
    this.setState({
      requiredError: true, 
      addressSelectError: true,
      recipientError: true,
    }, () => {
      console.log('required error', this.state.requiredError);
      console.log('address error', this.state.addressSelectError);
      console.log('recipient error', this.state.recipientError);
    })
```

Or bind it at the constructor like

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work
    this.processCheckout = this.processCheckout.bind(this);
  }
```

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: I have tried console logging in render, and all of them are true but at the console log at the callback it is not reflected